# Use a wild card in StackDriver Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-stackdriver

I would like to use wildcard in Google StackDriver Logging filter.
However, according to the official website, filter can not use it.
Is there any method I can use?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to search for strings contained in text, just [type that string directly.](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/basic-filters#common-basic-searches)

```
Unicorn (text:Unicorn)
Finds all log entries containing unicorn, in any field and in any letter case.
```

If you want to add conditions in advanced filter to search in all pods that begin with "prefix", try like this `(note ':' instead of '=')`:

```
resource.type="k8s_container"
resource.labels.cluster_name="cluster-1"
resource.labels.pod_name:"prefix"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the following common [basic search example](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/basic-filters#common-basic-searches):

**Example:**

*A use of string like:* **`uni* (text:uni*)`**

> As explained in the above documentation "This is not a wildcard search. This search finds all log entries containing the 4-character string **`"uni*"`**. The Logs Viewer does not support regular expression searches and there are no special wildcard characters such as * or ?, in either the basic or advanced filter interfaces".

You may also submit this as a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) using the [Issue Trackers](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187203&template=0).